# Headphones don't work after update

Tags: headphones, 15.04, logitech

I updated to Ubuntu 15.04 from Ubuntu 14.10 a few days ago, and now my Logitech G230 headphones don't receive any sound. How can I fix this? PulseAudio Volume Control detects my headphones, and says they're working, but no sound comes through.

EDIT: Using `alsamixer` worked at first, but now it doesn't, and I get frequent bursts of static through my headphones now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a temporary solution that works for me:

In Terminal type `alsamixer`, there is a volume bar for headphone. Switch in on by pressing `M`

Comment: That worked at first, but now it will say it's on when no sound comes out.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem. I can correct it with the alsa mixer, but it reverts as soon as I unplug/plug back in the audio jack
To make Audio jack have an output I actually have to turn up the SPEAKER output on the Alsa mixer

Comment: Didn't work for me; headphones still don't work.