# Computer not detecting headphones after upgrading from ubuntu 14.10 to ubuntu 15.04.

Tags: upgrade, headphones, 15.04, speakers

After upgrading my pc from ubuntu 14.10 to ubuntu 15.04 my pc can no longer detect headphones and can only play through the speakers. how can i fix this?

Comment: I had the same problem, and [this link][1] fixed it.


  [1]: https://askubuntu.com/questions/614086/headphones-dont-work-after-update/614609#614609